# Return the content of an EF model's DbSet based on type

Tags: entity-framework, reflection

I have an entity framework context with tables EntityTypeA, EntityTypeB ... EntityTypeZ. I would like to create a method which returns an IEnumerable of IEntityModel, or in other words the content of the tables listed above.

I currently have a switch which, based on the type provided as argument, returns the content of the corresponding table.

Please consider the following code that I'm trying to factorize:

```
IEnumerable<IEntityModel> GetAllEntitiesByType(Type entityType)
{
    NorthwindEntities en = new NorthwindEntities();
    switch (entityType.Name)
    {
        case "EntitiesTypeA":
            return en.EntitiesTypeA;
        // all types in between
        case "EntitiesTypeZ":
            return en.EntitiesTypeZ;
        default:
            throw new ArgumentException("Unknown model type: " + entityType);
    }
}
```

I would be surprised if there were no other more concise way to achieve the same result (by using reflection for instance) but I can't seem to find a useful example.

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the non generic [`DbContext.Set`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679544(v=vs.103).aspx) method to get the corresponding [`DbSet`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset(v=vs.103).aspx) and then cast it to `IEnumerable<IEntityModel>` (important - do not use [`Cast`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696369(v=vs.103).aspx) method but regular C# cast operator):

```
IEnumerable<IEntityModel> GetAllEntitiesByType(Type entityType)
{
    NorthwindEntities en = new NorthwindEntities();
    return (IEnumerable<IEntityModel>)en.Set(entityType);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using generic repository pattern. [Here](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/814768/crud-operations-using-the-generic-repository-patte) you can find an example.

Then implement the `GetAllEntitiesByType` function in your repository like this:

```
IEnumerable<T> GetAllEntitiesByType()
{
    return entities.Set<T>();
}
```